# Xamarin forms application login using ASP.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have completed web part of my Project and deployed my website on azure. My project is designed on Web API Entity Framework. Now I need to design Mobile App of my project Cross Platform Xamarin. I know basics of Xamarin development but having difficulties in Login part. Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nkccb9ODr_A) I have done the followings

1. ApiServices.cs

   ```
   public async Task LoginAsync(string userName, string password)
   {
       var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
       {
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username",userName),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",password),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","password"),
       };
       var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://epolleasy.azurewebsites.net/Token");

       request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
       var client = new HttpClient();
       var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
       var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       Debug.WriteLine(content);
   }
   ```
2. LoginViewModel.cs

   ```
   public class LoginViewModel {

   private ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public ICommand LoginCommand
   {
       get
       {
           return new Command(async() =>
           {
               await _apiServices.LoginAsync(Username, Password);
           });
       }
   }
   }
   ```
3. LoginPage.xaml

   ```
   <StackLayout>
   <Entry Text="{Binding Username}" Placeholder="Username"/>
   <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Password"/>
   <Button Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Text="Login"/>
   <Button Text="Signup" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>
   </StackLayout>
   ```

The **problem** is, this all only generates a token just as shown in tutorial. I want to know what i need to do with this token or how can I get user to login in my application using my builtin project web APIs. I searched a lot but unable to find any good tutorial regarding this topic.

Comment: remember to use `httpS` since your `password` is plain-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably a CSRF Token. PAss this in your Headers along with any further requests. The CSRF has a lifetime and is basically alive for that one session.

For further info see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/authentication-and-authorization/

Answer (score 0):

I mobile up on successful login you will get token as you mentioned. You have to save this token and pass it as header when you call other API services.